# Zend framework and pthreads library implementation

Tags: php, zend-framework, pthreads

Im using pthreads (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) library in my Zend Framework project. The problem is new threads use different memory scope from whole ZF initialization. So from threads scope I can't reach Zend Framework functionality. So I need to load (initialize) whole Zend Framework in every single thread call. But I do not know how to do this properly... What Im already doing (ZF initialization in thread) and what is actually not working for me:

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
```

So any ideas? Do have any examples of loading properly the whole ZF thing?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The threads are in a different address space. However, when you create a Thread your environment, so far as loaded classes ( not objects ), functions, declared constants and ini entries are duplicated for the new context.

It appears that the object representing your application is a standard object, it should be the case that simply setting it to a member of a thread will make your application object available to the threading context. I cannot say if that is the correct thing to do, it doesn't seem useful to load the whole application in every Thread, I would imagine you want to load an instance of the framework but configure it differently for different tasks.

Here's a working example with ZF2 available in the threading context, as I said I don't know anything at all about the framework, but it might be helpful.

```
<?php
use Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader;
use Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader;
use Zend\Debug\Debug;

require_once 'Zend/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
$loader->register();

class T extends Thread {
    public function __construct($loader) {
        $this->loader = $loader;
    }

    public function run() {
        $this->loader->register();

        printf(
            "Executing Thread with ZF2 Loaded (%s)\n", Debug::getSapi() 
        );

        var_dump ($this->loader);
    }
}

$t = new T($loader);
$t->start();
?>
```

Comment: +Nice Trick .. I see this solving some other related issue

Comment: @JoeWatkins - Maybe it'd be useful if you linked this topic to the readme @ github, it took a while to get threads to autoload and after that I managed to find this post, which could have saved me a fair amount of time. Other than that, great job at providing userland threading for php :)